# JPQL ManyToMany Join based on codition

Tags: jpa, join, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, jpql

I need help with a JPQL Query.

I have the Entity `Author` and the Entity `Book`, they are related as ManyToMany relation in JPA, where the Author has the owning side.
What I need is a query to get all Books that were not written by a certain Author.

I tried already writhing a query but it does not work.

```
Select b From Book b Where (Select a From Author a where a.AuthorId = :authorId) Not Member of b.authors) Or b.authors Is Empty);
```

What am I missing for the query to work properly? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you get any exception? If not how does the generated SQL look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these, it should actually work, but it's gonna be more helpful when you share the errors you get.

`SELECT b FROM Book b JOIN b.authors authors WHERE (:authorId NOT IN authors) OR (:authorId Is Null);`

Or

`SELECT b FROM Book b JOIN b.authors authors WHERE (:authorId NOT IN b.authors) OR (:authorId Is Null);`

Hope it could help you.